# appengine java command line deploy, refresh token

Tags: google-app-engine

What is the appropriate way to deploy a Java AppEngine app via the command line without requiring a google username / password or any user input?

I'm able to do this with Python / Go apps using the --oauth2 command, retrieving the refresh_token from the .appcfg_oatuh2_tokens json file, and then running the following command:

```
appcfg.py --oauth2_refresh_token=$MY_TOKEN update hello-world-app/
```

But I haven't been able to figure out an equivalent for Java. I'd like to add Java Appengine deploys to our CI product, [drone.io](https://drone.io), to compliment our existing Heroku and Dotcloud deployment options. Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

appcfg.sh supports the `--oauth2` flag since version 1.7.2.

So you would just need to do:

```
appcfg.sh --oauth2 update <path-to-your-app>
```

The tool will generate the token the first time and persist it. There's no `--oauth2_refresh_token` option, but you could achieve the same by copying the generated oauth credentials, which are in the user directory and called `.appcfg_oauth2_tokens_java`.

Comment: yes you are right, I can just have a user enter the access and refresh tokens, and I can auto-generate the .appcfg_oauth2_tokens_java file. That should do it!